# Creation of folder inside the internal storage

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to create folder inside the internal storage(android/data/com.AppName) in android and similarly for IOS. How to do that using phonegap?

Similarly what is the internal storage path for ios?

Comment: Did you take a look here? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343204/create-a-directory-in-phonegap-application

Comment: File plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: Those create the folder in sd card, i want to create in internal storage (android/data/com.AppName) in case of android and similarly for ios.

Comment: not sure, what do you mean by a folder inside internal storage?

Comment: @AAhad like I need to create a folder firstFolder inside data/data/com.AppName/files/files/ in android and similarly in ios(internal storage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On Android:** as per [official API docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)

add one of these two lines to **config.xml:**

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Without this line, the **File plugin** will use **Compatibility** as the **default**. If a preference tag is present, and is **not** one of these values, the application will **not** start.

**On iOS**

add one of these two lines to **config.xml:**

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Without this line, the **File** plugin will use **Compatibility** as the **default**. If a preference tag is present, and is **not** one of these values, the application will **not** start.

**Strongly recommended to read [API docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) before starting.**

Comment: where will the Library will store , can you give me the path of that storage and also will it be deleted at the time of uninstalling the app.

Comment: anything within the App's own folder will be deleted on uninstall...this is a normal behavior

Comment: Please read the docs about file structure, how to save and where to save...read these titles "Where to Store Files" & iOS File System Layout. hope will help you.