# Cordova badge is not cleared in ionic app after reinstall the app also

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Hi i'm using cordova badge in one of my ionic app [ANDROID], its working fine.
But the problem is:
- suppose app is working and badge count is set to 3.
- am clearing this count on sign out.
- but user will uninstall the app with out sign out.
- when the user reinstall the app, in the app icon badge is showing 3.
- old badge count was not cleared.

Is there any way to clear the badge before uninstalling the app?

**NOTE :** am using android_debug.apk file to install the app. App is not downloading or installing from any google play store.

Comment: if you are storing bage count in local storage you can clean that variable at time of app uninstallation, or if you set badge from API may be you don't have this issue.

Comment: @Naitik How would you propose he detects that an app is about to be uninstalled? There is simply no such feature in Android or iOS.

Comment: but you can do follwing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142889/removing-file-created-by-phone-gap-on-uninstalling-app

Comment: hai @Naitik i tried your link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142889/removing-file-created-by-phone-gap-on-uninstalling-app but its not clearing the badge.

Comment: Where is the problem? Just delete the badge on first app start.

Comment: hi @Joerg,  am doing that.  but its something appointment kind app, am displaying today's appointments count in badge.  so testing team wants to clear that badge count on reinstall the app.